# PHP inserting data into database with a twist

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have two fields, 1 is a textarea:

```
<textarea name="siteplan" id="siteplan" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
```

the other is an image field:

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">
```

this is the text I am inserting into my textarea:

```
var city = new google.maps.LatLng(43.20976, -79.96596);
                var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.20500, -79.96390);
        var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(43.2052,-79.9684),
            new google.maps.LatLng(43.2146,-79.9627));

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: city,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

                var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                        '<p><b>Ancaster Glen</b> - 435 Garner Rd E, Ancaster</p>' +
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
                        maxWidth: 300
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: point1,
                        map: map,
                        title:"Ancaster Glen"
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });

        var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
            '/images/IMAGE.png',
            imageBounds);
        oldmap.setMap(map);
```

What I am trying to do insert this text into my database and replace IMAGE.png with the name from the input file. Is this possible? Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what is the text you are inserting into the text area?

Comment: You probably want to do that when outputting the data rather than inputting it.

Comment: J-Dizzel, the javascript code is what I am inserting, I am looking to replace the IMAGE.png with the file name in my input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by a simple $text = str_replace('IMAGE.png',$_FILES["image"]["name"],$_POST['siteplan']) and insert the $text to the database.

Be sure to filter the $text input before to store it in order to avoid sql injections or persistent XSS.

Answer (score 1):

yes , in your PHP file when you receive the content of your text area you just make use of srt_ireplace

like so

```
$siteplan=$_POST['siteplan'];
$image=$_POST['image'];
$imageName=$image["tmp_name"];
$siteplan=srt_ireplace('IMAGE.png',$imageName,$siteplan);
```

and make sure to sanitize and secure your input data , never trust the user